# Updating Bootstrap Modal Via Ajax - why doesn't modal('show') need calling here?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

This code (from a wordpress plugin I'm developing) appears to work - opening a modal, making an ajax call, retrieving some data and displaying it in the modal, using Bootstrap 3 and (native WP) jQuery 1.11.

What I'm confused by is, why does the modal open without calling `$('#registrantModal').modal('show');`?

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.get_registrants').click(function(){
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        classDescription = $(this).attr("data-classDescription");
        className = $(this).attr("data-className");
        $('#registrantModal').find('#ClassTitle')[0].innerHTML = className;
        $('#registrantModal').find('#ClasseRegistrants')[0].innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-3x fa-spin"></i>';
        var htmlClassDescription = '<div class="modal_class_description">';
        htmlClassDescription +=  decodeURIComponent(classDescription) + '</div>';
        htmlClassDescription += '<h5 class="mz_registrants_header">Registrants</h5>';
        $('#registrantModal').find('#class-description-modal-body')[0].innerHTML = htmlClassDescription;
        var ajaxFn = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/api/registrant/'+$(this).data('className'),
                error: function(data) {
                                    fakeResponse = {"message":"Student of a Class", "type":"success"}
                    if(fakeResponse.type == "success") {
                            htmlRegistrants = '<ul class="class_registrants">';
                            htmlRegistrants += '<li>' + fakeResponse.message + '</li>';
                            htmlRegistrants += '</ul>';
                            $('#registrantModal').find('#ClasseRegistrants')[0].innerHTML = htmlRegistrants;
                    }else{
                            $('#registrantModal').find('#class-description-modal-body')[0].innerHTML = "error!";
                    }
                } // ./ Ajax Success
            }); // ./Ajax
        } // ./ajaxFn
        setTimeout(ajaxFn, 1000);
    });  // ./Click
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<a class="modal-toggle get_registrants btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registrantModal" data-classDescription="Some Details about this event" data-className="Student of a Class" data-classID="12345" href="#">An Event</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="registrantModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title ' . $className .'" id="ClassTitle"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="class-description-modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="ClasseRegistrants"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeill/pL1xznu9/13/).

(In the actual code I use the wordpress admin ajax and call an actual uri and data points to a function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your attributes in the `a` element makes your modal open on click.

`data-toggle="modal"`

`data-target="#registrantModal"`

It is equivalent of `$(element).modal('show')`.

See the live example in the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo)

Comment: sweet! i see i can "toggle" `data-toggle="modal"` in the HTML and `$('#registrantModal').modal('show');` in the js with same result. any readon why one might be more appropriate in this case than another?

Comment: In your case it is not important, but sometimes you want to show modal not on click event.